# Implement tower::Layer using async block and ServiceFn

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tower

I'm trying to implement a [tower](https://docs.rs/tower/0.4.13/tower/) [Layer](https://docs.rs/tower/0.4.13/tower/trait.Layer.html) using the [tower::layer_fn](https://docs.rs/tower/0.4.13/tower/layer/fn.layer_fn.html) and [tower::service_fn](https://docs.rs/tower/0.4.13/tower/fn.service_fn.html) helper functions like this (compiles fine):

```rust
use std::convert::Infallible;
use tower::Service;
use tower::util::ServiceFn;


tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
    .layer_fn(|mut service: ServiceFn<_>| {
        // Just do nothing except calling the downstream service
        tower::service_fn(move |request| {
            service.call(request)
        })
    })
    .service_fn(|request: String| {
        // Echo service
        async move {
            let response = request;
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(response)
        }
    });
```

Because I have multiple `.await` points in my real code, I would like to avoid [implementing `Layer` by hand, i.e. `Service::call()`](https://docs.rs/tower/0.4.13/tower/layer/fn.layer_fn.html#example), but instead do so in an `async` block. For the echo service, that does work fine, as shown above. However, for the service *inside* the `layer_fn`, that doesn't compile:

```rust
tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
    .layer_fn(|mut service: ServiceFn<_>| {
        tower::service_fn(move |request| {
            // Just do nothing except calling the downstream service
            async move {
                let response: Result<String, Infallible> = service.call(request).await;
                // Do something with response, await'ing thereby
                response
            }
        })
    })
    .service_fn(|request: String| {
        // Echo service
        async move {
            let response = request;
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(response)
        }
    });
});
```

I get the following error, but I don't know how to help the compiler with the typing:

```
error[E0698]: type inside `async` block must be known in this context
  --> src/main.rs:32:64
   |
32 |                     let response: Result<String, Infallible> = service.call(request).await;
   |                                                                ^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
note: the type is part of the `async` block because of this `await`
  --> src/main.rs:32:85
   |
32 |                     let response: Result<String, Infallible> = service.call(request).await;
   |                                                                                     ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type inference in async contexts is sometimes less powerful than in sync context. Unfortunately, the only solution I can see is to use the nightly `type_alias_impl_trait`:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

type Fut = impl Future<Output = Result<String, Infallible>>;
type Callback = impl Fn(String) -> Fut;
tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
    .layer_fn(|mut service: ServiceFn<Callback>| {
        tower::service_fn(move |request| {
            // Just do nothing except calling the downstream service
            async move {
                let response: Result<String, Infallible> = service.call(request).await;
                // Do something with response, await'ing thereby
                response
            }
        })
    })
    .service_fn::<Callback>(|request: String| {
        // Echo service
        async move {
            let response = request;
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(response)
        }
    });
```

Or by boxing both the callback and the future:

```rust
type Fut = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<String, Infallible>>>>;
type Callback = Box<dyn Fn(String) -> Fut>;
tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
    .layer_fn(|mut service: ServiceFn<Callback>| {
        tower::service_fn(move |request| {
            // Just do nothing except calling the downstream service
            async move {
                let response: Result<String, Infallible> = service.call(request).await;
                // Do something with response, await'ing thereby
                response
            }
        })
    })
    .service_fn::<Callback>(Box::new(|request: String| {
        // Echo service
        Box::pin(async move {
            let response = request;
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(response)
        })
    }));
```